# Galois extension of function field with Galois group C_6

Tags: algebraic-geometry, function-fields

Let $p>3$ be a prime number and let $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ be the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.

Is there a curve $C$ such that the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{p}(C)/\mathbb{F}_{p}(t))$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_6$?

In a way, this should be some analogue of the cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{7})$, but I'm not really sure how to explicitly construct it.

Comment: The obvious idea is $\mathbb{F}_{p^6}(t)$. If $6|p-1$, $\mathbb{F}_p(t^{1/6})/\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ also works, and without any extension of scalars.

Comment: @Aphelli I think the thing the OP might be missing, otherwise I think they might have asked a different question, is the equivalence between field extensions and curves: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BY1